# save each grepped line as a separate .txt file using bash

Tags: bash, loops, grep, save

I have a file .txt with some informations, i need to grep the "Report:" line and save each line in a different .txt file!

it should result something like this in the end:

```
case1.txt 
case2.txt 
case3.txt
```

I tried to

```
cat cases.txt| grep Report: | while read Report; do echo $Report | > /home/kali/Desktop/allcases/case.txt done
```

but it didnt work and just created one file called case.txt containing the last grepped "Report:"

I dont know if i was very clear then i'll show this screenshot:

[cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNmx0.png)

I wanted to split all theses reports in a different .txt file for each report!

These case informations are from a game, so dont worry!

Comment: Why don't you simply use a counter, which you increment for each line, so that you do a `echo $Report >$case{counter}.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

`awk` would be better suited than `grep` and a `while loop`. If acceptable, you can try;

```
awk '/^Report/{cnt++;close(report); report="case"cnt".txt"}/./{print > report}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne '++$i && `printf "$_" > case$i.txt` if /Report:/' cases.txt
```

This is looping over cases.txt and shelling out `printf "$_" > case$i.txt` if the line matches `/Report:/`

Because it's perl there's some syntax and precedence tricks in here to make it terse and confusing.